# JSONata (or JS) - group and sum JSON array / objects

Tags: javascript, json, node-red, jsonata

I want to 'groupsum' an array of objects with JSONata, from the following array:

```
payload = [
 {"id":"Irr-1","name":"Irrigation","timedif_s":7.743},
 {"id":"Irr-2","name":"Irrigation","timedif_s":2.749},
 {"id":"Lig-2","name":"Lights","timedif_s":1.475},
 {"id":"Irr-1","name":"Irrigation""timedif_s":1.07},]
```

The results must look like:

```
[{"name":"Irrigation", "sumtimedif": 11.562},
 {"name":"Lig-1", "sumtimedif": 1.475}]
```

I have tried:

```
payload.name{"name":payload.name,"sumtimedif":$sum(timedif_s)}
```

But I only get back an empty string.

```
{ empty }
```

Any advise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following JSONata expression will do this:

```
payload{
  name: $sum(timedif_s)  /* group by name */
} ~> $each(function($v, $k) {
 {"name": $k, "sumtimedif": $v}  /* transform each key/value pair */
})
```

The first part of the expression does the grouping and aggregation, and the second part transforms each group (key/value pair) into the format you want. http://try.jsonata.org/ByxzyQ0x4

Comment: What if I want to add a 2nd group-by keypair, and get totals with that, I tried to modify your statement in several ways, I cannot get it to work? Let's say a new keypair in above --> "date" : "2018-12-24" ?    @Andrew-Coleman

Answer (score 0):

I found another good post that helped me: [Most efficient method to groupby on a array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-a-array-of-objects).

Not sure if this can  be done in JSONata, so I reverted to JS, as follows:

```
var arr = msg.payload ;
arr1 = groupBy(arr, 'name', 'timedif_s' ) ;
msg.payload = arr1 ;
return msg;
//---------------------------------------------
function groupBy(array, col, value) {
    var r = [], o = {};
    array.forEach(function (a) {
        if (!o[a[col]]) {
            o[a[col]] = {};
            o[a[col]][col] = a[col];
            o[a[col]][value] = 0;
            r.push(o[a[col]]);
        }
        o[a[col]][value] += +a[value];
    });
    return r;
}
```