# JSONata - Grouping, summing, then dividing by the sum of the group

Tags: grouping, jsonata

I am trying to group by a key and then calculate the sums for those groups (as shown in this example: [JSONata (or JS) - group and sum JSON array / objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53895674/jsonata-or-js-group-and-sum-json-array-objects)). Then I would like to divide the original number by the group sum.

Sample:

```
{
    "positions": [
        {
            "ticker": "AAPL",
            "marketValue": 100
        },
        {
            "ticker": "AAPL",
            "marketValue": 200
        },
        {
            "ticker": "ATVI",
            "marketValue": 200
        },
        {
            "ticker": "ATVI",
            "marketValue": 300
        },
        {
            "ticker": "BAC",
            "marketValue": 100
        },
        {
            "ticker": "BAC",
            "marketValue": 400
        },
        {
            "ticker": "BAC",
            "marketValue": 200
        }
    ]
}
```

The result I want (where "group-weight" equals each item's marketValue divided by the sum of the same-ticker marketValues:

```
{
    "positions": [
        {
            "ticker": "AAPL",
            "marketValue": 100,
            "group-weight": 0.3333
        },
        {
            "ticker": "AAPL",
            "marketValue": 200,
            "group-weight": 0.6667
        },
        {
            "ticker": "ATVI",
            "marketValue": 200,
            "group-weight": 0.4
        },
        {
            "ticker": "ATVI",
            "marketValue": 300,
            "group-weight": 0.6
        },
        {
            "ticker": "BAC",
            "marketValue": 100,
            "group-weight": 0.1429
        },
        {
            "ticker": "BAC",
            "marketValue": 400,
            "group-weight": 0.5714
        },
        {
            "ticker": "BAC",
            "marketValue": 200,
            "group-weight": 0.2857
        }
    ]
}
```

I can get the sum of the groups using:

```
positions{`ticker`: $sum(marketValue)}
```

but can't get that next step where I divide by the group sums.

https://try.jsonata.org/m_xPDfncW

Answer (score 0):

```
(
    $totals := positions{ticker: $sum(marketValue)};
    positions.{
        "marketValue": marketValue,
        "ticker": ticker,
        "group-weight": marketValue / $lookup($totals, ticker)
    }
)
```

See https://try.jsonata.org/jLDI1Pgnx